# Regex in git insteadOf

Tags: git, git-config

Is it possible to use regular expressions while using **insteadOf** in gitconfig ?

I am trying to create url redirects while *git clone <url>*
Example: http://username@domain/scm/<project>/<repo>.git be redirected to https://git@bitbucket/domain/<repo>.git

.gitconfig:

[url = "https://git@bitbucket/domain/ "]
insteadOf = http://username@domain/scm/*/

Here, '*' is not allowed in gitconfig. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

More info on git **insteadOf** - https://jonhnnyweslley.net/blog/how-to-rewrite-git-urls-to-clone-faster-and-push-safer/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a regex or glob in the `insteadOf` pattern.  However, you can specify multiple `insteadOf` patterns for the same URL, which may work for you if the number of items is small.

Comment: Unfortunately the project count is >100